# nothing written through pipeline when using vmstat

Tags: linux, bash

Some command pipelines that I expect to write to the terminal or to a file don't write anything until a lot of time has passed.

It looks like the data is not being line-buffered but if I use Ctrl-C to send SIGINT none of the expected output appears. What causes that?

I want to modify and collect each line of vmstat output as it comes without losing data when I finally decide to stop collecting.

Here are some closely related examples:

```
output to terminal: vmstat -n 1 | sed ''
output to terminal: echo foo | sed '' | tee /dev/null
output to file: vmstat -n 1 > somefile
output to file: echo foo | sed '' > somefile
no output to terminal: vmstat -n 1 | sed '' | tee /dev/null
no output to file: vmstat -n 1 | sed '' > somefile
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577865/is-sed-blocking

Comment: Thanks wu. Please could you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`stdbuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) with option `--output=L` or `--output=0` to make the output line buffered or unbuffered respectively

```
stdbuf --output=L vmstat -n 1 >somefile
```